# Eigen fill up Sparse RowMajor matrix with triplets

Tags: c++, sparse-matrix, eigen

I am trying to fill up a Sparse RowMajor matrix. Following the guide I was using the triplets method:

```
Eigen::SparseMatrix<double, Eigen::RowMajor> data_matrix(rows, cols);
....

void get_data(const char *dir_name, std::vector<T> tripletList, Eigen::SparseMatrix<double, Eigen::RowMajor> data_matrix) {
uint64_t row_iter = 0;

for (std::string file_n : sorted_files) {
   ...
   if (words.find(word_freq[0]) != words.end())
       tripletList.push_back(T(row_iter, words[word_freq[0]], std::stoi(word_freq[1])));
   }

   row_iter++;

}

data_matrix.setFromTriplets(tripletList.begin(), tripletList.end());
```

However, this approach generates an empty matrix. I couldn't find examples of filling RowMajor matrices with the triplet list method, is it not possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works for me, here is a selfcontained example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/SparseCore>
#include <vector>
using namespace Eigen;
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  int m = 3, n = 7;
  SparseMatrix<double, RowMajor> M(m,n);
  typedef Triplet<double,int> T;
  vector<T> entries;
  for(int k=1; k<=9;++k)
    entries.push_back( T(internal::random<int>(0,m-1), internal::random<int>(0,n-1), k) );
  M.setFromTriplets(entries.begin(), entries.end());
  cout << MatrixXd(M) << "\n";
}
```

that produces:

```
 1  0  0  8  4  0  0
 0  3  0  6  0  0  0
16  0  0  2  0  0  5
```

**EDIT:**

So the problem is in the structure of your code, I see that `get_data` gets the triplet list and the sparse matrix by value, whereas they are modified by this function, so you most likely want to pass them by reference.

Comment: Sorry forgot to add the initialization of the matrix to the code shown becuase it was in another function. I believe initializing with `Eigen::SparseMatrix<double, Eigen::RowMajor> data_matrix(rows, cols);` already set the size, right?

Comment: Indeed, so could you confirm that it does work for you if using a `ColMajor` matrix?

Comment: In the meantime I've found an alternative solution in one of your answer on another forum (funny :) ). At the moment I'm doing `Eigen::SparseMatrix<double, Eigen::RowMajor> data_matrix(cur_rows, cols);    data_matrix.reserve(cur_rows * 100000);` and filling it with `data_matrix.insert(row_iter, words[word_freq[0]]) = std::stoi(word_freq[1]);`  and it seems to work fine. Do you know if there is any noticeable performance difference between the two alternatives?

Comment: But it should still work with the setFromTriplets, and my self-contained example shows.

Comment: Ok when I have a second to test, I'll try with the triplets method and let you know. In the meantime I'll select your answer as accepted :)

Comment: I think I found the root of your issue in the prototype of `get_data`, see my updated answer.